# jQuery resizable and draggable window can't resize

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I was using this [demo](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/jquery-resize-drag/) example which had working dragging and resizing but when I downloaded it only the dragging is working.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.css">

<style>body,input{font-family:Calibri,Arial;margin:0px}h1{margin:0 0 0 20px}html,body,#container{height:100%}body>#container{height:auto;min-height:100%}#header{height:50px;background-color:#ddd;border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;width:100%}#footer{font-size:12px;clear:both;position:relative;z-index:10;height:3em;margin-top:-3em;text-align:center}.demo{width:150px;height:150px;padding:5px;background-color:#f81;position:absolute;top:150px;left:300px}#content{padding-bottom:3em}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div class="demo ui-draggable ui-resizable">Move Me!!... Resize Me!!...<div style="-moz-user-select: none;" unselectable="on" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div><div style="-moz-user-select: none;" unselectable="on" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div><div unselectable="on" style="z-index: 1001; -moz-user-select: none;" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se"></div></div>
</div>
<script>$(function(){$('.demo').draggable().resizable();});</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if all the jquery libraries are loaded.

In this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0yjj5s/) I've used `jquery version 1.9.1` with `jQuery UI 1.9.2`. And its working.

Comment: Oh thank you, turns out I was using the wrong version of Jquery, loaded the versions you said and it worked.